# How to transform a sequent notation to rule form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I can write this proposition in sequent notation:

$$(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow (\neg P \lor Q)$$

as this one in rule form (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)#Formal_notation)):

$$\frac{(P\rightarrow Q)}{(\neg P \lor Q)}$$

But how can I transform, for example, these into rule form?

$$(P\rightarrow Q)\leftrightarrow(\neg(P\land\neg Q))$$
$$((P\land Q)\rightarrow R)\rightarrow((P\land\neg R)\rightarrow\neg Q)$$
$$((P\lor Q)\rightarrow (P\land S))\rightarrow(\neg P\lor\neg Q)$$

Are there any specific rules to follow? I saw a similar example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Proving_logical_formulas) but I cannot follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in sequent notation it would be:

$$(P \to Q) \vdash (\neg P \lor Q)$$

rather than

$$(P \to Q) \to (\neg P \lor Q)$$

The latter is a tautology and as such can be used as an axiom in an axiom system, but the latter is not a sequent.

Second, for

$$(P\rightarrow Q)\leftrightarrow(\neg(P\land\neg Q))$$

you would need two rules:

$$\frac{P\rightarrow Q}{\neg (P \land \neg Q)}$$

and

$$\frac{\neg (P \land \neg Q)}{P\rightarrow Q}$$

The

$$((P\land Q)\rightarrow R)\rightarrow((P\land\neg R)\rightarrow\neg Q)$$

is easy, as that just becomes:

$$\frac{(P\land Q)\rightarrow R}{(P\land\neg R)\rightarrow\neg Q}$$

The

$$((P\lor Q)\rightarrow (P\land S))\rightarrow(\neg P\lor\neg Q)$$

can be written as a rule

$$\frac{(P\lor Q)\rightarrow (P\land S)}{\neg P\lor\neg Q}$$

but please note that this is not a valid inference, and indeed

$$((P\lor Q)\rightarrow (P\land S))\rightarrow(\neg P\lor\neg Q)$$

is not a tautology!

Comment: Thanks for the solution! However, I would appreciate if you could give me a further explanation or a step by step method of how to do it exactly. Are there any general rules?

Comment: @Stepii All I did was to look at the main connective: if that is a conditional, then you can immediately separate between the premise and conclusion. If it is a biconditional, then you get two rules.

Comment: And that's all? Are there any special cases? What if I had $$((p\to r)\lor(q\to r))\to((p\land q)\to r)$$ After which condition do I need to separate?

Comment: @Stepii The main connective is the third $\to$, so that's where it separates: $$\frac{(p \to r) \lor (q \to r)}{(p \land q) \to r}$$

Comment: But could it also be like this?
$$
\begin{array}{l}
(p\to q)\lor(q\to r)\\
p\land q\\
\hline
r\\
\end{array}
$$
Or this?

Comment: D@Stepii Yes, you are right, that also works! OK, so it is more complicated than I indicated at first ... but not too complicated: you can say that every time you have a conclusion whose main connective is a cponditional, you can separate it, moving the antecedent to the premises, and keeping the consequent as the conclusion.

Comment: And what about `and`? Can I separate it too?

Comment: @Stepii Well, if you have $p \to (q \land r)$, then you could introduce two rules: $$\frac{p}{q}$$ and $$\frac{p}{r}$$.  Or, if you have $(p \land q) \to r$, that could become $$\frac{p \land q}{r}$$, which in turn can become $$p$$$$\frac{q}{r}$$

Comment: Thanks. You could edit the answer and include this explanation.